# Autofill an Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-authentication

I'm making an application with C#, this application will automatically navigate to a SharePoint site and gather some information. I have basic User Rights to the site (Meaning I'm not at a Site Admin), the SP site uses Integrated Windows Authentication which looks like this, [image]

How can I get the C# application to autofill the needed credentials when the WebBrowser control navigates to the site?

This is a very basic break-down,
- Application Opens
- 'Navigate' Button is clicked 
- WebBrowser1 Control Navigates to the SP Site and autofills the supplied credentials (Within the code).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I'm using to complete this operation,

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(new Uri("http://spSite"), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
        client.Credentials = cc;
```